# Transform ndarray to torch tensor filling with zeroes

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, tensor

I have a `numpy.ndarray` of `numpy.ndarray`, for example, `[[10], [23], [12, 18, 15]]`. I also have a fixed max length of each row in this array. How can I transform this array to `torch.tensor` with shape of row equal max len of first `np.ndarray`, filling with zeroes? Can I do it without a loop?

The output `torch.tensor` should be like this

```
[[10, 0, 0], [23, 0, 0], [12, 18, 15]]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: In this example, the fixed max length would be 3?

Comment: Yes, in this example, it's 3

Comment: try `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([torch.tensor(a) for a in arr], batch_first=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy padding matrix of different row size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676539/numpy-padding-matrix-of-different-row-size)